# Relation between reduced chi square and Akaike criterion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, model-selection, chi-squared-test, aic

In choosing the best fit between different curves, supposing the errors are distributed normally, I can do the following things:

- Calculate the reduced $\chi_r^2=\frac{\chi^2}{N_b-N_p}$, where $N_b$ is the number of bins and $N_p$ is the number of parameters, for all the fits and choose the smallest.
- Calculate the Akaike Information Criterion $AIC=\chi^2+\frac{2N_p(N_p+1)}{N_b-N_p-1}$, for all the fits and choose the smallest.

What is the relation (if any) between the two methods?

Comment: The "AIC" you have there looks like the small-sample corrected AIC (AICc). It's probably easier to see the relationship between the first statistic and the original, asymptotic version ($-2 log L + 2 N_p$ or $\chi^2 + 2 N_p$ in cases where you can replace the first term that way). Divide both sides by $N_b - N_p$, and you can see the relationship clearly: AIC/($N_b - N_p$) is the reduced chi-square plus an additional term. I don't know if that helps you any.